# Handling 404 & 500 in DXA 2.2

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2

Is there have been any improvements in DXA 2.2 in regards to handling 404 & 500 errors? In Tridion 2013 we are getting a 200 HTTP Status Code for binaries (images for example) that do not exist on the website but we should actually be getting a 404 status code.

Thanks